# Warning during the clipping with rasterio mask

Tags: raster, gdal, rasterio

I am trying to clip raster with geodataframe geometry and save it according to the gid. So I have 150 polygons in the geodataframe and using the threading I am clipping each polygon and writing to the new .tiff file individually. this works for 149 polygons but it is not working specifically to one geometry by printing:

```
NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform, gcps, or rpcs. The identity matrix will be returned.
  _rasterize(valid_shapes, out, transform, all_touched, merge_alg)
```

my script:

```
with rio.open(img_rast) as img_rast:
            
            src_crs = img_rast.crs
            src_profile = img_rast.profile
            try:
                logging.info(f'Processing raster transforming {order_id} - {existence} - {gid}')
                if gid == '32608_76':
                    
                out_image, out_transform = rio.mask.mask(img_rast, gid_gdf.geometry, crop=True)
```

I have tried this one too:

```
clipped = img_rast.rio.clip(gid_gdf.geometry.values, gid_gdf.crs, drop=False)
clipped.rio.to_raster("/agrospace/planet_download/regional_processing/clipped_invert.tif", compress='LZMA')
```

and getting the same warning. As a result the tiff contains only NaN values...
What will be the reason?